# How to undo changes made by `lxappearance`?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I installed `lxappearance` for some styling and decided it was not what I wanted. Now when I `purge` it, the styling  remains.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; and `lxappearance` is a GTK2 app & will have no impact on GNOME which is GTK3, I at least cannot see how it relates.  What exactly is the issue (and which OS/release). You may have altered GNOME GTK2 theme settings which will remain until you revert the changes (which is unrelated to `lxappearance` except it can change them)

Comment: @guiverc added OS version (18.04). I'm not entirely familiar with GTK2 and 3 difference. However, my dropdowns and highlights have different colors in FF. Also in `xdg-open` colors look different. Just want to revert this, what should I do?

Comment: I would asap apply security updates; as 18.04.2 implies you've not applied security fixes/patches since before [Aug-2019](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/) with a fully-patched system reporting [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/), also note those dates are the ISO release details; installed systems upgraded before that date.

Comment: GTK2 is a *deprecated* toolkit (Gimp+GNOME toolkit); GTK version 2 which was replaced by GTK3 which itself is now in maintenance mode with work now on GTK4.  `lxappearance` is *deprecated* and only impacts GTK2 apps such as `hexchat` (or old LXDE stuff); GNOME-Shell is GTK3 (has been since ~2011); thus changes made by your use of the old app will be hard to find/correct in GTK3 GNOME3 as you changed settings in an *deprecated* tool. You could try gnome tweak tool; but it'll depend on what you changed

Answer (score -1):

All I needed was:

```
mv ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini.bk
```

`~/.gtkrc-2.0` was also created, which I didn't want to change.